# Wordpress site has been hit with gutenblock-64/stealth process

Tags: linux, process, wordpress

The process has been taking up a lot of resources and has been sending DDos(?) to other sites.

It ran under as www-data.
What it does :

1. it downloaded under wordpress's wp-content folder and run itself.
2. After that it removed itself from wp-content folder to evade scanner but the process will be still resident in the memory.

I managed to recover the process file by copying /proc/PID/exe
and my limited knowledge only showed it's packaged by upx using linux strings commands to peek inside.

Anyway to know that how the malware managed to run itself? How to know where the malware managed to sneak in?

Comment: You'd possibly be better off at the SE's WordPress-specific section. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com (I checked and it looks like it should be considered on-topic there.)

Comment: If you would mount that filesystem with *noexec*, the filesystem where your PHP is able to write anything, it won't happen.